# SELECT COUNT with Group BY only return value of 2

Tags: php, sql, group-by, count, echo

I have 6 records 3 of which has identical School and I want to get the result of counting how many school there are inside my database but it only returns the value of 2

```
$tblnum1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS ttldata FROM engoralgrade3 WHERE Years = '$yrr' GROUP BY School";
$tblnum = mysqli_query($conn, $tblnum1);
$tblnm = mysqli_fetch_array($tblnum);

echo $tblnm['ttldata'];//input should be 3
```

[This what my data base looked like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhJjj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your table, every school do have 2 rows.
maybe u want to count how many distinct school there are, so change the sql to:

```
select count(distinct School )from engoralgrade3
```

or u want to distinct the school name, try :

```
select distinct School from engoralgrade3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query it will work

```
$tblnum1 = "SELECT * FROM engoralgrade3 WHERE Years = '$yrr' GROUP BY School";
$tblnum = mysqli_query($conn, $tblnum1);
$tblnm = mysqli_num_rows($tblnum);

echo $tblnm ;
```

it may be the var $yrr is not identical for all six records in database which cause make returnred value is 2 not 3 .